# Modify a property value in json string

Tags: java, json, objectmapper

i have a json string like this

```
{
  "code": "200",
  "data": "",
  "datadetail": null,
  "message": "Khách hàng không tồn tại",
  "description": "KH_NOTFOUND:"
}
```

because the value of data property is "" so that the object mapper can't not map that field in to Java POJO, is that anyway to modify the value of data property to specific string like below

```
 {
  "code": "200",
  "data": "no data",
  "datadetail": null,
  "message": "Khách hàng không tồn tại",
  "description": "KH_NOTFOUND:"
}
```

here is the error [image: 1]

detail

> Can not instantiate value of type [collection type; class java.util.ArrayList, contains [simple type, class vnptpay.collection.adapter.partner.water.laichau.Datum]] from String value (''); no single-String constructor/factory method

here is my target java object class to map

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
"code",
"data",
"datadetail",
"message",
"description"
})
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class GetBillResponse implements Serializable{

@JsonProperty("code")
private String code;
@JsonProperty("data")
private ArrayList<Datum> data = null;
@JsonProperty("datadetail")
private Object datadetail;
@JsonProperty("message")
private String message;
@JsonProperty("description")
private String description;
@JsonIgnore
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
```

here is my mapping code

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
GetBillResponse obj = null;

obj = mapper.readValue(output.toString(), GetBillResponse.class);
```

Comment: Changing the empty string to "no data" won't help. The object mapper is trying to construct an `ArrayList<Datum>` and so expects an array in the JSON. Unless you provide a special mapping, a simple string won't do.

Comment: but the return string is type of "", is there any solution to handle this case ?, i don't have the permission to control the json string output

Comment: Isn't it possible that you get `data: []`  or `data:null`?

If it's possible I hope your problem should get resolved.

Comment: What is the value of `data` going to be when it's not empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming output.toString() is your JSON string you could add .replace("\"\"", \"{none}\"). Java *should* be able to interpret this as an ArrayList with one element (maybe my syntax is wrong, but there is definitely a way to initialise an ArraList from a String).

Edit: Now that I think about it, you probably need JSON-syntax, not Java-syntax, so .replace("\"\"", \"[]\") or something like that.

Comment: u have any idea to change those syntax ?

Comment: What do you mean by changing syntax? I mean that you have to write [] for JSON to recognize it as an empty list as supposed to {} or {none} Java.

Comment: you idea is right, i did change  the string of data from " '' into [], now it's became empty array so it no longer cause error

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, you're mapping from a wrong type.

In your JSON `"data": ""` refers to a String field name *data*. When the java code is mapping it, as the default value passed is a string, it tries to look for an *ArrayList* constructors that takes a String as you defined it as list in your Java code:

```
@JsonProperty("data")
private ArrayList<Datum> data = null;
```

So you have 2 options now:

- you send a valid JSON array that will be mapped to the list like `"data": []`. (assuming you have a constructor like `Datum(String value)`)
- You change the data mapping in your java code to a *String* and map it to an ArrayList later (if for instances your splitting the String on commas or so)

Also for the record I wouldn't advise you yo map data to an *ArrayList* but rather map it to a *List* as it is common best practice to refer to interfaces and not implementations !